# Convert text to a link in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hello My problem is that I have a Column in Grid view named TweetText, Which always has a Url in it. I want to make that URl as a click able link. I have managed to do this on page load. But when I change the page number of the grid, The Text of TweetText remains same i.e unchanged. Writing my code here.  I am doing this code on GridView1_PageIndexChanged too. But nothing is helping. One more thing is that I dont want to make the whole column has a link. I just want to make the Url in the Column as a link

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
                    String Url = SmartyPlants.Classes.TwitterData.GetUrlStrings(row.Cells[5].Text);
                    bool Check = SmartyPlants.Classes.TwitterData.IsUrlValid(Url);
                    int Index = Url.IndexOf(" ");
                    if (Url.Contains(" "))
                    {
                        Url = Url.Remove(Index);
                    }
                    String link = MakeLink(Url);
                    row.Cells[5].Text = row.Cells[5].Text.Replace(Url, link);
                }
            }
public static string MakeLink(string txt)
        {
            Regex regx = new Regex("http://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            MatchCollection mactches = regx.Matches(txt);

            foreach (Match match in mactches)
            {
                txt = txt.Replace(match.Value, "<a href='" + match.Value + "'>" + match.Value + "</a>");
            }
public static bool IsUrlValid(string url)
        {
            return Regex.IsMatch(url, @"(http|https)://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?");
        }
        public static string GetUrlStrings(string text)
        {
            MatchCollection ms = Regex.Matches(text, @"(www.+|http.+)([\s]|$)");
            string testMatch = ms[0].Value.ToString();
            return testMatch;
        }

            return txt;
        }
```

Comment: provide your grid markup and how are you getting this url ??? does it have some data source column entry??

Comment: make that coloumn as Template col and add a <a href runat="server" /> to it. In RowDataBound just find the a tag and set its src.(src means where it should redirect)

Comment: One more thing is that I dont want to make the whole column has a link. I just want to make the Url in the Column as a link

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use just `HyperLink` control in the gridview and use `Eval()`, if you already have data?

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='Default.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("id")%>' Text="TweetText"></asp:HyperLink>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

**OR**

you can even find the HyperLink inside GridView OnRowDataBound Event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    HyperLink myHyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1") as HyperLink;
    if(myHyperLink !=null)
    {
       //myHyperLink.NavigateUrl="URL"; 
    }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="id" Text="Details" ControlStyle-Font-old="true" 
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/pages/UserDetails.aspx?id={0}" />
```

set `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` dynamically or u can user `Hyperlink` in `itemtemplet`